# mining and trading cryptocurrency from laptop

Tags: miner-configuration, trading

I would like to safely start mining and trading cryptocurrency from my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04).

The solutions I found online are shady at best or unusable. The ecosystem that I would like to use is a desktop one that gives me the options to:

- Be as safe as possible
- Trade the cryptocurrency that I have with any other at any moment
- Mine the cryptocurrency that I want
- Cash-out at any moment without any cap via IBAN and only IBAN, if possible

If possible I would also like to interface this system with some local Python scripts that dynamically decide what to buy, sell or mine.

What should I do? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to bitcoin.stackexchange.com. Since Bitcoin can't currently be mined with a laptop, this isn't a question that can be properly answered here.

Comment: Bitcoin can be mined with pen and paper, it certainly can be mined with a laptop. Should it be done, is an entirely different question.

Comment: I have no cost on electricity

Answer (score 2):

You can't mine Bitcoin on your laptop. Even with free electricity you will never make anything. So this is a pointless question.

If you just want to learn how the mining algorithm works, that's a totally different question, as long as you know you will never withdraw any actual money from it.

> Cash-out at any moment without any cap via IBAN and only IBAN, if possible

Pretty much all crypto-fiat exchanges are going to have limits due to regulatory requirements.

But essentially for your trading activity you're just going to sign up for one of the exchanges and look into their trading/withdrawal APIs.

Comment: My point is not mining a huge amount, even a tenth of a cent would be fine, it would be just to have a non-empty wallet.

Comment: Also, isn't the point of crypto to be non-centralized? What does it mean ' regulatory requirements ', from who?

Comment: @SO_32 You would literally never make any money at all doing this, thus it's a pointless question. I'm not sure that you'd ever be able to solve a single share, thus it'll appear as if you aren't doing any work at all. Crypto is decentralized, but the fiat banking system is very much centralized. If you want to exchange your crypto for fiat money (euros, USD, etc) you'll need to do it through an exchange which will need to comply with government regulatory requirements to maintain their access to the fiat banking system.